# How do you transfer villagers from the demo to the full game?

Tags: bravely-default

I have some villagers in Norende on my demo version. By playing the demo version you earn up to 7 rewards packs that can be transferred over to the full game as well as up to 20 villagers. Now that I have bought the full game, I would like to transfer those villagers over. I heard there was a way to do this, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You can't transfer Norende's population to another village.

Comment: You definitely need to clarify what you mean for this question.  Do you mean "how can I transfer my villagers to another village"? "How can I transfer my villagers to another person's game"?  Be descriptive, please.  And also please explain how you discovered 'transferring villagers' was even a thing you can do in this game - I've heard quite a bit about the game, but don't know about this function.

Comment: The question is as clear as it needs to be. You can transfer up to 20 villagers from the demo version into the full game. When you get the ability to upgrade Norende it should just give you the option to transfer them over iirc. There is no effort on your part. It should just pop up. It has been a few months though. I forget the exact progression.

Comment: As @Reafexus said, it's rather straightforward. I have an answer ready for you, but with the question on hold, I cannot post it. [Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68310222)'s the relevant source. When you start a new game, it asks if you want to transfer. When you unlock the village in a full game save where you did transfer, the villagers will be there (up to 20).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68310222

When you start a new game in the full game it'll ask if you want to use the demo data.

There isn't anything else that needs to be done on your part.